# React Native app get user installation date

Tags: react-native, date, expo

I am trying to get the date the user installed my react native app (I am using expo as well) , is there a built library or some other way to do this?

Comment: On the first start of the app you can save  the current date in AsyncStorage, that can be one of the solution.

Comment: @Kailash solution will work only if the user launches the app, not when installing it. to be fair, unless the app fetches the OS about it, I don't know a way to run code on install (only on bundle time).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the installation date for Android and Windows platforms using this package [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info).

The name of the method you have to use is getFirstInstallTime(), here is the link to it https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getfirstinstalltime.